# use many ssi with fastcgi_cache in nginx

Tags: caching, nginx, fastcgi, ssi

I am using fastcgi_cache in nginx in order to speed up the php, which connects database and select articles.

Here is my flow:

first, I add a ssi-include in my index:

```
<\!--# include file="/templates/1-5-list.html" -->
```

then, I add a location route to handle html -> php in nginx-conf

```
location ~(\d*?)-(\d*?)-list.html
{
    try_files $uri /articles/list.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
}
```

after that, I apply `fastcgi_cache` for list.php

```
# outside the server{}
    fastcgi_cache_path /home/cache/articles levels=1 keys_zone=articles_cache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
# outside the server{}

location ~/list.php$ {
    fastcgi_cache articles_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 2h;
    ...
}
```

Everything is ok right now, and the caching function well.

However, If I have two or more ssi in my index:

```
<\!--# include file="/templates/1-5-list.html" -->
<\!--# include file="/templates/2-5-list.html" -->
```

The second ssi return exactly the same result as the first one, FAIL!

I search inside the cache directory, And I found that, the `KEY` using for caching is `httplocalhost/articlesGET`, which means such two ssi are sharing the same `KEY`. And I think this is the cause.

My question is how can I modify the `fastcgi_cache_key` such that they can have different `KEY`? I've tried adding `fastcgi_cache_key` inside `location{}` but fail.

Answer (score 0):

`$request_uri` in nginx SSI subrequest refers to parent request URI.
Use `$uri` in included fragment cache key instead:

`fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$uri$request_method;`